# QTableView для больших данных

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть таблица в БД `SQLite`, записей пока немного, около 10000. Но в работе ожидается гораздо-гораздо больше.

**А вопрос вот в чем:** можно ли как-то заставить `QTableView` не спрашивать у модели все 10000 записей, а ограничится каким-то разумным минимумом, например = видимые + 100 выше + 100 ниже?

Хочу избавится от полной загрузки в память данных всей таблицы. Хочется мочь подгружать данные по мере перелистывания/скроллинга таблицы.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore выглядит как то что вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.